# Not rendering element using Autocomplete mui/material

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I have an array of states which the `Autocomplete` component show up. But when I select one state I should render a component that relies on which state were selected.
Nothing is rendered but the state is selected inside the code.

The component is as it follows

```js
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from '@mui/material';

import styles from './/styles.module.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

type JSXElement = any;

const statesString = [
  'Acre',
  'Alagoas',
  'Amazonas',
  'Brasília Distrito Federal',
  'Ceará',
  'Espírito Santo',
  'Goiás',
  'Maranhão',
  'Mato Grosso',
  'Mato Grosso do Sul',
  'Minas Gerais',
  'Pará',
  'Paraíba',
  'Paraná',
  'Pernambuco',
  'Piauí',
  'Rio de Janeiro',
  'Rio Grande do Norte',
  'Rio Grande do Sul',
  'Roraima',
  'Santa Catarina',
  'São Paulo',
  'Sergipe',
  'Tocantins',
];

const locations = [
  {
    name: 'Acre',
    locations: [
      {
        name: 'Aeroporto de Rio Branco',
        address:
          'Avenida Plácido de Castro – Vila Aeroporto – Rio Branco CEP: 69923-900 AC Telefone: 68-3211-1000',
        lat: -9.98417,
        lng: -67.88333,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default function SearchBar() {
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState('');

  function renderSelectedStateWithMap(stateName): JSXElement {
    console.log(stateName);
    locations.map((state) => {
      console.log('state', state);
      if (state.name === stateName) {
        state.locations.map((location) => {
          return (
            <div className={styles.selectedStateContainer}>{location.name}</div>
          );
        });
      }
      return <></>;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.searchBarContainer}>
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: string | null) => {
          setSelectedState(newValue);
        }}
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={statesString}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Escolha o Estado" />
        )}
      />
      {renderSelectedStateWithMap(selectedState)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `renderSelectedStateWithMap` does not return the `<div>` even though the `map()` find the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any element in `renderSelectedStateWithMap` function. Therefore, you need to return your result element.

For example:

```
function renderSelectedStateWithMap(stateName): JSXElement {
  return (
    <>
      {locations
        .filter((state) => state.name === stateName)
        .map(({ locations }) =>
          locations.map((location, locationIdx) => (
            <div key={`location-id-${locationIdx}`}>{location.name}</div>
          ))
        )}
    </>
  );
}
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-sea-vldw7x?file=/Demo.tsx).

Comment: Another workarout that worked was using useEffect watching stateSelected and updating it directly on the JSX. But that worked too!

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. @Ernanni